# Can a Bash alias command be inserted into my macOS terminal text input so I can tweak and run it?

Tags: bash, terminal, clipboard, macos

I have some Bash aliases which I use to perform standard day-to-day tasks in my macOS terminal using the Bash shell.  Sometimes I find myself wanting to run a one-off command very similar to an alias I already have configured.  My current approach is to type `alias my-alias-name`, copy the portion of the result within the command section of the quotes, paste it back into the Terminal input, and then edit it.

This approach is distracting and a little time consuming since command auto-complete doesn't work after I've started typing the word `alias` (so I either have to type in the full alias name or autocomplete my alias first and then go back to the start of the line and type `alias`).  Also it means I have to use my mouse and replace my current clipboard contents, plus identify and copy the correct portion of the output.

Is there a way to automatically insert the alias command into the Terminal input without having to resort to copy/pasting a selection of a command output?

> ```bsh
> $ alias example-alias="ls -l"
> ```
>
> <exa><kbd>tab</kbd>,<kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd><alias >
>
> ```bsh
> $ alias example-alias
> alias example-alias='ls -l'
> ```
>
> Highlight the text between the single quotes with mouse, <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>

For instance, is there a way to write an alias/script `expand-alias` such that the following will insert the alias command into the command input to be modified?

```
expand-alias example-alias
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per [this tip](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1416125/1108305), one can use <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> to perform alias, history, and shell expansion on the current line.  Therefore one can type/autocomplete the alias command, type this key combination, and have the text inserted into the input to be modified.

A downside of this approach is that it requires remembering a three-key combination for something that is only used occasionally.  Depending on how your brain works, it might be harder to remember than a well-named command would be.